# Failed to allocate bytes in OpenCV

Tags: c#, opencv, memory-management, memory-leaks, emgucv

I am using *Emgu.CV* to extract frames from video files and extract faces from every frame, the problem is the application runs out of memory after a while. I think i release memory and dispose every object i create. Here is the method, any optimization, ideas will be appreciated.

```
public List<FileItem> ExtractFacesFromImage(FileItem selectedFrame, string outputFolderPath, int minNeighbors, double scaleFactor, int widthIncrement = 80, int heightIncrement = 102)
{
    lock (lockObj)
    {
        _currentFrame = new Image<Bgr, byte>(selectedFrame.Path);
        _gray = _currentFrame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
        var result = new List<FileItem>();

        using (_face = new HaarCascade(_xmlFilePath))
        {
            if (_gray != null)
            {
                var facesDetected = _gray.DetectHaarCascade(_face, scaleFactor, minNeighbors,Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_ROUGH_SEARCH,new Size(20, 20));

                for (int index = 0; index < facesDetected[0].Length; index++)
                {
                    var imgName = SaveExtractedFace(outputFolderPath, facesDetected,
                                    index, widthIncrement, heightIncrement);
                    result.Add(new FileItem
                    {
                        IsSelected = true,
                        Path = imgName,
                        Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imgName)
                    });
                }
                DisposeObject(_gray);
                DisposeObject(_currentFrame);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}

private void DisposeObject(IDisposable disposable)
{
    if (disposable != null)
    {
        disposable.Dispose();
        disposable = null;
    }
}

private string SaveExtractedFace(string outputFolderPath, MCvAvgComp[][] facesDetected, int index, int widthIncrement, int heightIncrement)
{
    var f = facesDetected[0][index];

    var cropRectangle = GetNewRectangle(f.rect, _currentFrame.Width, _currentFrame.Height, widthIncrement, heightIncrement);

    _tempImage = _currentFrame.Copy(cropRectangle);
    string imgName = outputFolderPath + "\\" + UniqueNameManager.Generate() + ".jpg";
    _tempImage.Save(imgName);
    DisposeObject(_tempImage);
    return imgName;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was using Emgu.CV version 2.1, in version 2.4 the problem is fixed. I think they fixed bugs or added some enhancement to their code. I recommend using version 2.4 instead of version 2.1

Comment: Thats It Not Bug I Am USing Emgu 2.4.0 But I Have Also This Problem

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run this code, and not use global or general variable.

```
public List<FileItem> ExtractFacesFromImage(FileItem selectedFrame, string outputFolderPath,
    int minNeighbors, double scaleFactor, int widthIncrement = 80, int heightIncrement = 102)
{
    lock (lockObj)
    {
        var currentFrame = new Image<Bgr, byte>(selectedFrame.Path);
        var gray = _currentFrame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();
        var result = new List<FileItem>();

        using (_face = new HaarCascade(_xmlFilePath))
        {
            if (gray != null)
            {
                var facesDetected = gray.DetectHaarCascade(_face, scaleFactor, minNeighbors,Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_ROUGH_SEARCH,new Size(20, 20));

                for (int index = 0; index < facesDetected[0].Length; index++)
                {
                    var imgName = SaveExtractedFace(outputFolderPath, facesDetected, index, widthIncrement,
                                                    heightIncrement);
                    result.Add(new FileItem
                    {
                        IsSelected = true,
                        Path = imgName,
                        Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imgName)
                    });
                }

            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}

private string SaveExtractedFace(string outputFolderPath, MCvAvgComp[][] facesDetected, int index, int widthIncrement, int heightIncrement)
{
    var f = facesDetected[0][index];

    var cropRectangle = GetNewRectangle(f.rect, _currentFrame.Width, _currentFrame.Height, widthIncrement, heightIncrement);

    _tempImage = _currentFrame.Copy(cropRectangle);
    string imgName = outputFolderPath + "\\" + UniqueNameManager.Generate() + ".jpg";
    _tempImage.Save(imgName);
    DisposeObject(_tempImage);
    return imgName;
}
```

Comment: @Henry - please forgive my ignorance.... You should explain the code you provided. If its essentially Wael's code, you should explain what you changed. Otherwise, folks are going to move to delete your answer.